# Still worth using bloom filter if your database already does?

Tags: postgresql, design-patterns, redis, rdbms

I have read in a couple of places that some databases use bloom filters for finding a match when querying a database. In my example I'm using Postgresql which is one of those databases.

My question comes up when talking about implementing a bloom filter with Redis which has a module that allows you to use a bloom filter when entering a member in a set. (Keep in mind the complexity of the lookup process though, not retrieving that value from disk)

Now the benefits of using Redis is to store values in memory, which when then trying to retrieve that value is more performant vs looking it up in a rdbms because that value is stored on a disk.

In my example, say I'm checking if a username already exists, is it still worth using Redis in memory solution with a bloom filter vs just checking with a Postgresql query?

My flow is something like:
`CheckIfUserExsits() // using Redis bloom filter`
`If TRUE then confirm with rdbms // do to x% probability of false positive nature of bloom filter`
`If rdbms == MATCH then reply with "User does exist"`
`Else don't check rdbms at all // do to 0% probability of false negative nature of bloom filter`

This flow is supposed to be more preformant because you're not querying a rdbms and doing this quickly via memory lookup returning `false` more efficiently.

However since all I care about is whether a member exists or not, to increase performance on replying with `false`, does the Redis step really help? Because if Postgresql is already querying a table using a bloom filter then the performance should already be relatively fast.

Comment: As your query will most like have a WHERE clause on the primary key, it will look up the row through a B-Tree index. That lookup is pretty much constant in time regardless of the size of the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So are you saying that most likely I would be getting no performance gain doing this Redis step?

Comment: Well, you do save the roundtrip to the database. Depending on the latency of that, doing the Redis lookup does offer a performance gain - but only you can test how big that is

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm assuming you're talking about network latency so say if Redis and Postgesql sit on the same machine and my service which calls Redis or Postgresql sits on another machine then virtually the network latency would be the same?

Comment: Not only network latency. There is also overhead involved in parsing, analyzing and running a SQL statement which is probably higher than a call to Redis

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The advantage of bloom is that it is very compact and so can perhaps fit in memory.  Even if the Btree is a constant cost at 2 random page reads, that is still a very expensive constant, compared to 0 random page reads.

Answer (score 2):

> I have read in a couple of places that some databases use bloom filters for finding a match when querying a database. In my example I'm using Postgresql which is one of those databases.

Could you provide links to the things you were reading?

PostgreSQL does have a bloom filter index type extension (in "contrib"), but the index has to be created explicitly and it would not be useful for your use case anyway.  It answers the question, for each individual row, "does this row satisfy a set of conditions". It does not answer the question "does any row in this table satisfy this one single condition".

PostgreSQL also has a C-language bloom data structure for internal use, but again your requirement is not one of those things it is used for.

Bloom filters of the type you want would be hard to implement in the face of PostgreSQL's ACID/MVCC model and its storage model.

If you really need this (and I doubt you do) then using redis seems like a good tool for the job.  But how will you keep them in sync?

Answer (score 1):

Don't add Redis unless you actually have performance issues. It adds a second datastore and development will be significantly slowed down and see more bugs because every data change needs to be synchronised between the two.

Redis also doesn't help much when it just replaces a function that's at the core of what Postgres also does (well). Postgres also uses memory to cache data. Just make sure it's configured with appropriate memory limits.

Where Redis can be useful is in caching "derived" data, i. e. anything the database and your application have spent significant time on.

Bloom filters is similar:  do use them when you need hundreds of thousands of lookups every second. But default to using your existing database. Postgres is capable of rather decent performance –– I've been surprised by it quite a few times.

Only optimise after measuring and identifying a problem.

Comment: "Only optimise after measuring and identifying a problem" These problems seem to come up a lot when creating a popular application. It is my hope that my application does acquire a lot of users. My application is suppose to be production ready so are you suggestion I should only deal with such problems when they come up to reduce design & code complexity at the beginning?

Comment: @RyanSam Set up a clone and fabricate users and see what happens.  It will be a lot of work, but less work than making random changes based on unsubstantiated theories.

Comment: Imho, if you are considering a hyped addition to your architecture, you want to add Kafka before you add Redis. You are still committing to a possibly over-engineered architecture, but at least you will mostly avoid synchronization issues.